# Print text to screen in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: text, printing, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to log some text on the screen, but not to all actors at once. I have several ai car actors, which all have a Scene Capture Component 2D component, on which their camera view can be seen.

I want to print to that object, but I cannot find any suitable function for this purpose. I found different print/draw text functions, but their target is either HUD or Canvas or Context, or simply the main screen. I tried to cast to one of the target types that have a function for this operation, but it always fails since Scene Capture Component 2D is not a subclass of any of them.

Is that even possible to do what I want?

(I use Unreal Engine 4.25 version with Blueprints.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a way to this would be to add a HUD to each actor and have a text as a UI widget in it. Then you could play the visibility and Value of that text to show what you need at any point.